# Validate whether value in one table is the same as in related table - performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

Let's say I have two tables and I'm doing all the operations in .NET Core 2 Web API.

Table A:

```
Id,
SomeValue,
TeamName
```

Table B:

```
Id,
Fk_Id_a (references Id in table A),
OtherValue,
TeamName
```

I can add and get records from table B indepedently.

But for every record in Table B **TeamName** has to be the same as for it's corresponidng Fk_Id_a in Table A.

Assume these values comes in:

```
{
    "Fk_Id_a": 3,
    "SomeValue": "test val",
    "TeamName": "Super team"
}
```

Which way would be better to check it in terms of performance? 1ST way requires two connections, when 2nd requires storing some extra keys etc.

1ST WAY:

- get record from Table A for Fk_Id_a (3),
- check if TeamName is the same as in coming request (Super team),
- do the rest of the logic

2ND WAY:

- using compound foreign keys and indexes:
- TableA has alternate unique key (Id, TeamName)
- TableB has foreign compound key (Fk_Id_a, TeamName) that references TableA (Id, TeamName)

SQL SCRIPT TO SHOW:

```
ALTER TABLE Observation
ADD UNIQUE (Id, PowelTeamId)

GO

ALTER TABLE ObservationPicturesId
ADD FOREIGN KEY(ObservationId, PowelTeamId) 
REFERENCES Observation(Id, PowelTeamId)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

EDIT: Simple example how the tables might look like. TeamName has to be valid for FK referenced value in Table A.

```
Table A
ID | ObservationTitle | TeamName
---------------------------------------
1  | Fire damage      | CX_team
2  | Water damage     | CX_team
3  | Wind  damage     | Dd_WP3

Table B
ID | PictureId | AddedBy | TeamName  | TableA_ID_FK
-----------------------------------------------------
1  | Fire      | James   | CX_team   |  1
2  | Water     | Andrew  | CX_team   |  1 
3  | Wind      | John    | Dd_WP3    |  3
```

Comment: Why do you even have `SomeValue` and `TeamName` in table B at all? That's wasted space.

Comment: SomeValue is example value, can be anything - I've updated the other one to OtherValue to avoid confussion. Let's say a TeamName is a business requirement.

Comment: Show real sample data. Hypothetical stuff makes it hard to understand. What are some sample rows that would be in A and B?

Comment: @dfundako Sure - I've edited and posted some sample in the bottom of the post

Comment: I you are repeating the the value of the FK then you have it wrong.

Comment: Another approach is to use triggers to prevent "bad" data. Normalizing the schema so that it can't have "bad" data is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise, the 2nd option would be faster because there is no comparison to check (the foreign key will force that they match when inserting, updating or deleting) when selecting the rows from the table. It would also make a unique index on table A.

That being said, there is something very fishy about the structure you mention. First of all why is the `TeamName` repeated in table B? If a row in table B is "valid" only when the `TeamName` match, then you should enforce that no row should be inserted with a different `TeamName`, throught the ID foreign key (and not actually storing the `TeamName` value). If there are records on table B that represent another thing rather than the entity that is linked to table A then you should split it onto another table or just update the foreign key column when the team matches and not always.

The issue is that you are using a foreign key as a *partial* link, making the relationship valid only when an additional condition is true.

Comment: Thanks. Well I agree, for sure repeating the data in tables is not good pattern. Normally I would denormalize data and store this by foreign key reference, but it was the structure given to me.

But even if the data was kept as FK reference, the validation should still happen through compound foreign key, or you would go for other way?

Comment: If you keep the compound foreign key, then the validation will be done at the moment you update the foreign key values and the posterior selects would go faster. You will need to do additional updates when a team name changes, or go with updating cascades.